# Axis options in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0.1111,0.1112,0.1113]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a, b, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

a) I would like the three numbers in b to appear in my y axis, instead of what I get: +1.11e-1 at the top, and then subtruction in the y axis.

b) I would like the axis not to overlap with the first and last point.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert `plt.yticks(b)` in your code. And import at the beginning of your script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0.1111,0.1112,0.1113]
plt.plot(a, b, 'ro')
plt.yticks(b)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You could also do this with the axis parameter and a subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0.1111,0.1112,0.1113]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3))
ax.plot(a, b, 'ro')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(b))
ax.set_yticklabels(b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It does not change anything and I get a different output than you. I am using jupyter notebook. What might be the problem?

Comment: I also plotted in jupyter notebook with the magic `%matplotlib inline`-command. Do you get any error?

Comment: I also use %matplotlib inline and I do not get any error.

Comment: Actually it works in my mac, but it does not in my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is the second version working in ubuntu? I'm also working on a Mac

Comment: I just upgraded  the jupyter notebook in my Ubuntu machine, but still same problem.

Comment: Ans the axes approach with subplots? Is this working? I just added it to my answer.

Comment: What happens when you add `ax.set_yticklabels(b)` below `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(b))`? Is this working? It should update the axis.

Comment: Good. I added the line to the answer.